# In Risk when do I have to give up my turn?

Tags: risk

In Risk when it's my turn and I attack.
Do I give up my turn if I lose some troops while attacking or could I continue attacking until I want to give up my turn?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.  Edit this question to have only a single question, and ask the other two as separate questions.  That works much better for this format, in that it allows for a single best answer for each individual question.

Comment: That's much improved.

Answer (score 3):

Your turn does not end if you lose troops.  You may continue to attack until you either don't want to attack, or have no territories with 2+ troops adjacent to an enemy.

Comment: When editing to reflect an update to the question, you should leave your answer in the ideal form, rather than leaving both the original answer and your new answer. You can always get back to the original via the revision history. I've gone ahead and tried to do this; if there's something more that was supposed to be included to address the question in its current form, please do edit further.

Answer (score 1):

You could continue attacking as long as there is at least one soldier attacking your opponent's territory. Or you could choose to retreat, but that wouldn't mean giving up your turn. You could attack somewhere else, or move your troops to some other country.

Comment: Btw this is answered after he edited the question

Comment: it's worth noting that you need a minimum of two troops remaining in the territory you are attacking from

Comment: From the rules: https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf

Comment: - You must always have at least two armies in the territory you’re
attacking from.

Comment: - You may continue attacking one territory until you have eliminated all
armies on it, or you may shift your attack from one territory to another,
attacking each as often as you like and attacking as many territories as
you like during one turn.